# Can there be Java interfaces that aren't annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I see that @Interface is used to declare an annotation. Can @Interface be used to declare something other than an annotation as well?

If not, why not just call it @Annotation or something?

Comment: You mean like the regular ol' `interface` keyword we've been using for over 20 years? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: We don't "just call it @Annotation or something" because that would violate the Java Language Specification (JLS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can there be Java interfaces that aren't annotations?

Yes, regular `interface`s:

```
public interface MyInterface {...}
```

> Can @Interface be used to declare something other than an annotation as well?

No, `@interface` defines an annotation. And be careful with the letter case - it's smallcase `@interface`, not `@Interface`.

> why not just call it @Annotation or something?

Because annotations are a type of interface, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43959810/1803551) I gave to your other question,

> An *annotation type declaration* specifies a new *annotation type*, a **special kind of interface type.**

(bold emphasis is mine) and from the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html):

> Annotation types are a form of *interface*

Answer (score 0):

> I see that `@Interface` is used to declare an annotation.

Actually, it is `@interface` and the distinction is important; see [your other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43959782/139985).

> If not, why not just call it @Annotation or something?

1. Because they didn't.
2. Because `Annotation` would violate the style rules (as an identifier)
3. Because `annotation` was not reserved as a keyword.  Turning it into a keyword would potentially make lots of existing customer Java code non-compilable.

   (That is what they did with `enum` and it caused problems for some people.  It would cause *more* problems in this case ... because the amount of existing legacy Java code has grown in the last ~15 years.)

---

Seriously, there is little point asking questions of the form "why didn't they design Java the way that I would have done it?".   They won't actually help you in doing your job ... unless your job is designing programming languages.  And if it is, then you probably already understand that it is impossible to resolve conflicting PL design requirements in a way that satisfies everyone.