# Is @interface a keyword in Java?

Tags: java

How come all other annotations are capitalized and defined somewhere, but @interface isn't? Does that mean it is a keyword?

Comment: "Why" is hard, since it depends on the whims of the designers of the language.  My guess: `@interface` reuses the keyword `interface` which was already defined and lower case.  Other annotations start with upper case because they're based on the concept of a class, which in Java by convention are capitalized.  E.g. `public @interface Override {}`.

Comment: @markspace Annotations are a type (not the technical meaning of *type*) of interface, that's why they use the same keyword. Annotation names start with uppercase because its the name of a *type* (class, interface, enum, annotation). The `@inteface` declaration is not an annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is @interface a keyword in Java?

Not exactly.  The keyword is `interface`.  When you write `@interface` in your source code, it is equivalent to writing `@ interface`.  (Note the space between the `@` and the `interface` keyword.)

This is explained in [JLS 9.6.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6) with the additional note:

> *"Note that the at-sign (`@`) and the keyword `interface` are distinct tokens. It is possible to separate them with whitespace, but this is discouraged as a matter of style."*

---

> How come ...

Well they used `@` `interface` because an annotation is a kind of interface.  The JLS says so.

As for why `interface` and not `Interface`, this is a compromise:

- On the one hand, `interface` is a keyword in Java, and they need to use a keyword rather than an ordinary identifier in that context.
- On the other hand you have this apparent inconsistency between `@interface` and regular annotations ... where Java style rules say that the annotation identifier should start with an upper-case letter.
- On the other hand again, they couldn't have used `@annotation` or `annotation` because `annotation` was not **reserved** for future use as a keyword back when Java was a young language.

I guess they resolved this by saying that `@interface` is not an annotation and hence there is no inconsistency with "other" annotations<sup>1</sup>.

However, this is speculation.  We were not present when the design decision was actually made.

---

<sup>1 - Some people think that since `@interface` "looks like" an annotation it is one.  For those people, the lower case letter *should* be a semantic clue that their mental model is not correct, and a hint that they should lookup and read what the JLS says about it.  The JLS is not particularly easy to read, but it is well organized and *searchable* if you look at the PDF version.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

> Is @interface a keyword in Java?

No, according to [JLS 3.9. Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) `interface` is a keyword, but not `@interface`.

> How come all other annotations are capitalized and defined somewhere, but @interface isn't? Does that mean it is a keyword?

[JLS 9.6. Annotation Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6):

> An *annotation type declaration* specifies a new *annotation type*, a special kind of interface type. To distinguish an annotation type declaration from a normal `interface` declaration, the keyword interface is preceded by an at-sign (@).

You usually capitalize letters after the `@` sign because that's the name of the annotation. When you defined the annotation, you just use the `@interface` combination. This is the same with classes and other interfaces (and enums), the keyword `class`/`interface`/`enum` is lowecase, but the name of the type  (should) starts with uppercase.

```
public @interface   MyAnnotation {...}
//      ^lowercase  ^uppercase
```

and then

```
    @MyAnnotation
//   ^uppercase
    public class MyClass {...}
```

Comment: "You usually capitalize letters after the @ sign" But you usually don't capitalize the keyword `interface`.

Comment: @LewBloch Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: Yes, except for calling `@interface` "an" identifier. It's actually two tokens, neither of which is an identifier.